# Colocar elemento en el centro html y css

Tags: html, css

tengo una serie de puntos que quiero colocar en el centro de la pantalla.

El número de puntos es aleatorio, a veces vendrán más o menos.

El problema es que quiero que se ajuste al centro, pero lo que estoy consiguiendo es que empiece a partir del centro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código es:

```
  .carousel--Multi-4 {
    position: relative;
  }
  .carousel--Multi-4 .slick-dots {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: calc(50%);
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position: outside;
  }
  .carousel--Multi-4 .slick-dots li {
    float: left;
    height: 8px;
    width: 8px;
    margin: 0 6px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #dedede;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .carousel--Multi-4 .slick-dots .slick-active {
    background-color: #ec0000;
  }
```

Dichos "puntos" se generan automáticamente con la librería slick http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Gracias.

Del Cdn ->

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Código para crear el slick ->

```
   $('.carousel--Multi-4').slick({
                        arrows: false,
                        dots:false,
                        slidesToShow: 3,
                        autoplay: configuracion.autoplay,
                        autoplaySpeed: configuracion.duracionTransicion,
                        responsive: [
                            {
                                 breakpoint: 708,
                                 settings: {
                                     dots: true,
                                     infinite: true,
                                     slidesToShow: 1.25,
                                     slidesToScroll: 1,
                                     arrows: false,
                                     infinite: true,
                                     speed: 300
                                 }
                            }
                        ]
                      });
```

Comment: ¿Podrías poner también tu HTML? Sólo con el CSS es complicado ver lo que puede estar pasando.

Comment: ¿Estás usando los estilos que vienen con la librería? Por defecto los puntos están centrados.

Comment: Me estoy trayendo los cdn ->  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

Comment: Si quito los estilos, los "puntos" salen pegados a la parte izquierda de la pantalla, pero no son puntos, son los números  de los contenidos del carousel.

Comment: Te falta el css `slick-theme.css` que es donde le da estilos a los puntos. Por otra parte (aunque no tiene que ver con tu problema) ese CDN que usas no tiene la última version de slick, yo usaria `cdnjs` que esta más actualizado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trata de no usar `float: left` utiliza mejor `display: inline-block`

Este sería mi código modificado

```
.carousel--Multi-4 {
    position: relative;
  }
  .carousel--Multi-4 .slick-dots {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 0;
    rigth: 0;
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position: outside;
  }
  .carousel--Multi-4 .slick-dots li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 8px;
    width: 8px;
    margin: 0 6px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #dedede;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .carousel--Multi-4 .slick-dots .slick-active {
    background-color: #ec0000;
  }
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar y perdón por tardar, he ejecutado tu código, te comento, sale desde la parte izquierda de la pantalla y se están eliminando los estilos, por defecto salen los números del carousel, mi css, quita esos números y los pone como puntos rojos, tú código quita mis estilos y vuelve a poner los números del carousel. gracias.

Comment: entiendo por eso agregabas el `text-indent`solo es ponerlo entonces

Answer (score 1):

Si todos los puntos, o los puntos que aleatoriamente vayan a generarse los añades a un `<div>` en el que con css hagas que se coloque en el centro el bloque, y por por tanto, el contenido del mismo.

Por ejemplo:

```
<div class="container">
<!-- Aquí es donde se deben colocar los puntos -->
</div>
```

En el archivo css alienar el bloque:

```
.container {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar y perdón por tardar, La librería crea los elementos html <ul> <li> de forma autómatica y los mete en el dom a su placer, por lo tanto no puedo encerrarlos en ningún div. gracias.